# “bash: warning” every time starting a terminal

Tags: command-line, bash

Every time starting a terminal I get this message:

```
bash: warning: here-document at line 119 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
```

I believe I had tried to install Haskell stack recently and it did not appear to install correctly, this may be where the warning has cropped up from as it has only been showing since after this.

@George [when running command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oR855.png) this is what i see in terminal, this is the same line I mentioned in the earlier comment on repeat.

@John Hi these are the last few lines that come up when running that :

```
    r libreoffice loweb lobase localc
++++ /etc/bash_completion.d/libreoffice.sh:110:unset _def _dir _file _nosp _minusdd _minusdf
+++ /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:1984:unset i _blacklist_glob
+++ /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:1987:[[ /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion != \/\h\o\m\e\/\p\e\a\k\s/.bash_completion ]]
+++ /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:1987:[[ -r /home/peaks/.bash_completion ]]
+++ /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:1989:unset -f have
+++ /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:1990:unset have
+++ /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:1992:set +v
+++ /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:1993:unset BASH_COMPLETION_ORIGINAL_V_VALUE
bash: warning: here-document at line 119 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
++ /home/peaks/.bashrc:119:cat
+ /home/peaks/.profile:20:PATH=/home/peaks/bin:/home/peaks/.local/bin:/home/peaks/bin:/home/peaks/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

@John1024 Here is what comes up :

```
peaks@system64:~$ awk 'NR==119,NR==130' /home/peaks/.bashrc
cat >> ~/.bashrc <<EOF



export PATH="$HOME/.cabal/bin:/opt/cabal/1.22/bin:/opt/ghc/7.10.3/bin:$PATH"




export PATH="/home/peaks/.cabal/bin:/opt/cabal/1.22/bin:/opt/ghc/7.10.3/bin:/home/peaks/bin:/home/peaks/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"


peaks@system64:~$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Step 1: Symptom

The initial symptom was the error message:

```
bash: warning: here-document at line 119 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
```

This tells us that the problem is on line 119 but unfortunately does not tell us which file was running when the problem occurred.  Depending on system configuration, an interactive bash may run any of a large number of start up files.

#### Step 2: Diagnostic

To find out which lines of which bash start-up files are causing a problem, one can run:

```
PS4='+ $BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO:' bash -xlic ""
```

This starts an interactive (`-i`) bash login (`-l`) shell in diagnostic mode (`-x`) and runs an empty command (`-c ""`).  The bash prompt `PS4` is set to prefix each line of output with the file and line which caused it.

#### Step 3: Identifying the problem

Running the above diagnostic command, we found:

```
+++ /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:1993:unset BASH_COMPLETION_ORIGINAL_V_VALUE
bash: warning: here-document at line 119 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
++ /home/peaks/.bashrc:119:cat
+ /home/peaks/.profile:20:PATH=/home/peaks/bin:/home/peaks/.local/bin:/home/peaks/bin:/home/peaks/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

This indicates that the here-document problem comes from line 119 of the file `/home/peaks/.bashrc`

The relevant section of `.bashrc` is:

```
cat >> ~/.bashrc <<EOF



export PATH="$HOME/.cabal/bin:/opt/cabal/1.22/bin:/opt/ghc/7.10.3/bin:$PATH"




export PATH="/home/peaks/.cabal/bin:/opt/cabal/1.22/bin:/opt/ghc/7.10.3/bin:/home/peaks/bin:/home/peaks/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
```

Line 119 `cat >> ~/.bashrc <<EOF` is a problem.  It attempts to modify the `.bashrc` file while the file is being executed.  In this case, it had the effect of appending a new PATH definitions onto the end of `.bashrc`.  Apparently, the file ended up with a large enough number of such PATH statements to significantly delay bash's initialization.

#### Step 4: Remedy

The problem could be fixed by opening an editor and deleting the unwanted lines.  Linux offers a choice of editors.  The editor `vi` is guaranteed to be present on POSIX systems but it has a steep learning curve.  `nano` is widely available and good for newcomers because it is easy to use.  So, to solve the problem, we could run:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

And then go to the problem lines and delete them and save the file.

Alternatively, we can avoid having to learn a new editor by running the following command:

```
sed -i.bak '119d; 130,$d' ~/.bashrc
```

This command updates `~/.bashrc` in place, deleting line 119 and deleting from line 130 the end of the file.  For safety, a backup copy of the original `~/bashrc` is saved as `~/.bashrc.bak`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.bashrc` file is off from what I see, please run the following commands:

1. Make backup copy:

   ```
   cp ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc.newbak
   ```
2. Open it in your favourite editor and make the following changes `gedit ~/.bashrc` and change the following lines (from 119, I believe) :

   1. Your bashrc:

      ```
      export PATH="$HOME/.cabal/bin:/opt/cabal/1.22/bin:/opt/ghc/7.10.3/bin:$PATH" 

      export PATH="/home/peaks/.cabal/bin:/opt/cabal/1.22/bin:/opt/ghc/7.10.3/bin:/home/peaks/bin:/home/peaks/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin" 

      export PATH="/home/peaks/.cabal/bin:/opt/cabal/1.22/bin:/opt/ghc/7.10.3/bin:/home/peaks/bin:/home/peaks/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
      ```
   2. Changes to be made, Remove all but the last line from `step: 2.1` above:

      ```
      export PATH="/home/peaks/.cabal/bin:/opt/cabal/1.22/bin:/opt/ghc/7.10.3/bin:/home/peaks/bin:/home/peaks/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
      ```
   3. Save and close the editor.
3. Check if the `.bashrc` is ok:

   ```
   source ~/.bashrc
   ```
4. **If step 3 returns errors restore from backup with:**

   ```
   cat ~/.bashrc.newbak > ~/.bashrc
   ```

Comment: I have managed to resolve the issue now, thanks for all your help